# Constraints are not functional relations!

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, constrained-dynamics, poisson-brackets

I am reading a Wikipedia article on [Dirac brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_bracket). At the bottom of the page ["illustration on example provided"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_bracket#Illustration_on_the_example_provided) the article states that for a system with constraints:
$$
\phi_1 = p_x + \frac{qB}{2c}y \approx 0 \Longrightarrow  p_x = -\frac{qB}{2c}y,
$$
$$
\phi_2 = p_y - \frac{qB}{2c}x \approx 0 \Longrightarrow  p_y = \frac{qB}{2c}x.
$$

The Dirac bracket is given by:
$$
\{f, g\}_{DB} = \{f, g\}_{PB} + \frac{c}{qB}\{f, \phi_1\}_{PB} \{\phi_2, g\}_{PB} -
\frac{c}{qB}\{f, \phi_2\}_{PB} \{\phi_1, g\}_{PB} .
$$

The article then states that
$$
\{p_x, p_y\}_{DB} = - \frac{qB}{4c}.
$$

**My Computation**
\begin{align*}
\{p_x, p_y\}_{DB} &=
\{p_x, p_y\}_{PB} + \frac{c}{qB}\{p_x, \phi_1\}_{PB} \{\phi_2, p_y\}_{PB} -
\frac{c}{qB}\{p_x, \phi_2\}_{PB} \{\phi_1, p_y\}_{PB} 
\end{align*}

we have:
\begin{align*}
\{p_x, p_y\}_{PB}
&= 
\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial p_y}{\partial p_x} -
\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial p_x}\frac{\partial p_y}{\partial x}
+
\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial p_y}{\partial p_y} -
\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial p_y}\frac{\partial p_y}{\partial y} \\
&=
0 -(1)\left(\frac{qB}{2c}\right) + \left(-\frac{qB}{2c}\right)(1) - 0\\
&= - \frac{qB}{c}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\{p_x, \phi_1\}_{PB}&= 
\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial p_x} -
\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial p_x}\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x}
+
\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial p_y} -
\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial p_y}\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial y} \\
&=
0 - (1)(0) + \left(-\frac{qB}{2c}\right)\left(0\right) - 0 \\
&=
0
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\{\phi_2, p_y\}_{PB}&= 
\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial x}\frac{\partial p_y}{\partial p_x} -
\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial p_x}\frac{\partial p_y}{\partial x}
+
\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial y}\frac{\partial p_y}{\partial p_y} -
\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial p_y}\frac{\partial p_y}{\partial y} \\
&=
0 - 0 + 0 - 0 \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\{p_x, \phi_2\}_{PB}&= 
\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial p_x} -
\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial p_x}\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial x}
+
\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial p_y} -
\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial p_y}\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial y} \\
&=
0 - (1)\left(-\frac{qB}{2c}\right) + \left(-\frac{qB}{2c}\right)(1) - 0  \\
&=
0
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\{\phi_1, p_y\}_{PB}&= 
\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial p_y}{\partial p_x} -
\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial p_x}\frac{\partial p_y}{\partial x}
+
\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial p_y}{\partial p_y} -
\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial p_y}\frac{\partial p_y}{\partial y} \\
&=
0 - (1)\left(\frac{qB}{2c}\right) + \left(\frac{qB}{2c}\right) - 0 \\
&=
0
\end{align*}

So then I get:
\begin{align*}
\{p_x, p_y\}_{DB} &=
\{p_x, p_y\}_{PB} + \frac{c}{qB}\{p_x, \phi_1\}_{PB} \{\phi_2, p_y\}_{PB} -
\frac{c}{qB}\{p_x, \phi_2\}_{PB} \{\phi_1, p_y\}_{PB} \\
&= - \frac{qB}{c} - \frac{c}{qB}(0)(0) - (0)(0) \\
&= - \frac{qB}{c} 
\end{align*}

Which is not the same as the article suggested. So is the article incorrect?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [joigus](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/263785/joigus) in the comment section for pointing out I had broken the fundamental law of Lagrangian formalism:

**Constraints CANNOT be used before evaluating the Poisson brackets**

Hence, my Poisson brackets above were wrongly evaluated because I treated the constraints as actual relations between the canonical variables $q$ and $p$. In fact, the brackets should be evaluated as if the constraints were not there, then used at the end.

Comment: The Wikipedia article is correct.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks for helping to clarify. I don't think my poisson bracket calculations are incorrect as I have checked back and forth quite a few times. Am I perhaps using the Poisson bracket incorrectly? Would really appreciate if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Qmechanic is right. Your calculation has a mistake. Suggestion: Rather than getting tangled in explicit form for PB, use canonical PB relations. $\{p_{x},y\}_{PB}=\{x,p_{y}\}_{PB}=0$, $\{x,p_{x}\}_{PB}=\{y,p_{y}\}_{PB}=1$, $\left\{ p_{x},p_{y}\right\} _{PB}=0$. Surest way to get the signs right.

Comment: @joigus Hi sorry but wouldn't the $\{x, p_x\}_{PB} = 1$ be correct only when there are no constraints on the system? Because in this scenario we have:
$$
\{x, p_x\}_{PB} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial p_x} -
\frac{\partial x}{\partial p_x}\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial x}  +
\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial p_y} -
\frac{\partial x}{\partial p_y}\frac{\partial p_x}{\partial y} 
=
1 - 0 + 0 - \left(\frac{2c}{qB}\right)\left(-\frac{qB}{2c}\right)
= 2
$$

Comment: And where does the "weakly equals zero" enter the argument? $p_x$ is just "weakly proportional" to $y$. That is, only on the constraint surface.

Comment: IOW, I think the mistake would be in considering a weak equality as a functional dependence. It's an interesting point!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that,
$$
\phi_{1}=p_{x}+\frac{qB}{2c}y\approx0
$$
Does not imply that,
$$
p_{x}=-\frac{qB}{2c}y
$$
But only,
$$
p_{x}\approx-\frac{qB}{2c}y
$$
and conversely for $y$, $x$.
That is, $p_x$ is a function of $y$ *only on the constraint surface.*
Because the Dirac bracket is a derivative operator built by design to keep you on the constraint surface, while evolving, it has this dependence built in.

Not so with the ordinary Poisson bracket. The Poisson bracket does not reflect this dependence, and thereby,
$$
\{p_{x},y\}_{PB}=\{x,p_{y}\}_{PB}=0
$$
$$
\{x,p_{x}\}_{PB}=\{y,p_{y}\}_{PB}=1
$$
$$
\left\{ p_{x},p_{y}\right\} _{PB}=0
$$

If you redo your calculation with these canonical-bracket rules, all the formalism should go through.

Comment: Thank you. I had not realized I had broke the fundamental law of Lagrangian formalism. I realized it only when you had mentioned it in the comments